# Laravel - redirect any page to mobile version with htdocs

Tags: php, laravel, htdocs

I am developing an ecommerce using laravel 4.2 and I want this:

when the user access a link like "http://www.mystore.com/cart" in a mobile, redirect to "http://www.mystore.com/m/cart" and the same for all pages from the site.

I am trying make this with htdocs, but is not working.

How can i make this?

Comment: Enter the 21st century and start doing responsive design instead of a separate mobile site.

Comment: thanks for the answer, i think that is really the best solution

Answer (score -1):

Why not use Javascript to do that?

```
var url = window.location.wref; //get current URL
var str = url.substr(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1); //extract the last segment
var newUrl = url.replace(str,'/m/'+str); //replace last segment with '/m/' + last segment
console.log(newUrl);
```